# Is the graph of the following type possible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, binary-operations, semigroup-homomorphism

Let a simple undirected graph be denoted by $(V, E)$, where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ is the set of edges. Let each vertex of a graph be a natural number. Now, I want to define the graph's edge such that $(V_1\cup V_2, E)=(V_1, E)\mathbin{\pmb\cup} (V_2, E)$, where $\cup$ and $\pmb\cup$ are set union and graph union, respectively. How should I define the graph's edge such that the edge is preserved (or, above equality holds)?

The following is my failed attempt.

> let the edge of each graph represents "divides", i. e.,  vertices $ a$ and $b$ are  connected by an edge if and only if $a$ divides $b$ or, $b$ divides $a$. In this case, it is found that the above equality doesn't hold.

Comment: What are you given? I.e. are you given $V_1$ and $V_2$? Are they finite? Are they disjoint? Also, should it be $E_1$ and $E_2$? Otherwise, when you say $(V,E)$ do you mean $E$ restricted to the vertices in $V_1$?

Comment: @roundsquare yes they are given and finite. They may or may not be disjoint. Edge set $E$ should be same for all three graphs (i.e., one graph in l.h.s and two graphs in r.h.s).

Comment: Gotcha. So, in reality, what you really want is a function, $f$ from finite subsets of natural numbers, $X$, to a set of unordered pairs of $X$ such that $\forall X,Y, f(X) \cup f(Y) = f(X \cup Y)$. (By this I am thinking of $E$ as being created by $f$). Is this right?

Comment: @roundsquare Yes, we can think axactly in that way.  So, how can we define such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formulation from the discussion in the comments above, I don't think this is possible unless $f(X)$ only has edges between nodes and themselves for all $X$ i.e. $\forall X, f(X)\subseteq \{\{a,a\}|a \in X\}$.

Here is why: assume $X=\{n_1, ..., n_k\}$ and $f(X)=\{\{n_a,n_b\}, ...\}$ where $n_a \neq n_b$. Now, let's create two sets, $X_a=X-\{n_b\}$ and $X_b=X-\{n_a\}$. Then, we know:

- $\{n_a,n_b\} \notin f(X_a)$ since $n_b \notin X_a$
- $\{n_a,n_b\} \notin f(X_b)$ since $n_a \notin X_b$

But

- $\{n_a,n_b\} \in f(X)$
- $X=X_a \cup X_b$

To put it in graph terms, take a graph $G(E,V)$ and take any edge ${a,b}$. Then you can create two new graphs which don't have that edge by $a$ into one graph and $b$ into the other graph.

In fact, we can specify $f$ even more. The only way to get the desired property is that for any $a \in X$, $\{a.a\} \in f(X)$ iff $\{a.a\} \in f(\{a\})$ i.e. the question of whether or not to include $\{a,a\}$ is independent of the other vertices in $X$. (You can prove this using a similar argument to the above).

Comment: Would you please elaborate the sentence "$f(X)$ only has edges between nodes and themselves for all $X$."?

Comment: @gete yeah. I edited my answer to be more clear (and added a paragraph making the answer more specific).